# В игре пуля врезается в объект не в центре экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моей игре на юнити во время выстрела пуля вылетает из орудия и летит в сторону центра экрана. Но если игрок стоит слишком близко к объекту, в который стреляет, то пуля не успевает долететь до центра экрана и врезается в него посередине между центром и орудием. Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

```
 public Rigidbody projectile;
 public int speed = 50;
 public Transform startBulletPosition;

 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         Rigidbody clone;
         clone = Instantiate(projectile, startBulletPosition.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
         var centre = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f);
         var ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(centre);
         clone.velocity = ray.direction * speed;
     }
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Правка 1. DrawRay**
Траектория полета пули

```
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
Debug.DrawRay(startBulletPosition.position, ray.direction, Color.green);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не стрелять(проверять райкастом) , если препятствие  ближе, чем точка пересечения прямой вдоль которой летит патрон и прямой через центр экрана (в одной плоскости y=const). Или просто до определенной дистанции. И заменить на удар прикладом или игнорировать.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ не уверен, что они вообще пересекаются, а если и так, то на большом расстоянии от игрока. если от стены отойти довольно далеко, то все-равно пуля правее курсора врезается в стену

Comment: Сам установи точку на которую должно смотреть оружие

Comment: @Xumera_hZ как?

Comment: Ну сделай так чтобы z ось проходила через дуло пистолета,  сделай lookAt  на точку. Точку заранее установи вдоль направления куда смотрит камера

Answer (score 1):

В вашем конкретном случае, то, что пуля врезается в объект не в центре экрана - корректное поведение, так как вы используете для перемещения пули физику. Для получения желаемого вами поведения, нужно определиться с некоторыми моментами:

1. Важно ли вам, чтобы пуля была видимым объектом на экране?

Если нет, то в вашем случае, можно отказаться от использования `Rigitbody`, и заменить его на простой [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) или серию Raycast'ов. Это будет намного дешевле с точки зрения производительности. В противном случае, можно попробовать "схитрить" с траекторией полета, также отказавшиcь от `Raycast` в сторону перемещения объекта, например с помощью [Transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

2. Корректна ли траектория полета пули в текущей версии вашего кода?

Отладить траекторию полета пули в вашем случае будет очень удобно с помощью [Debug.DraRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html), который нарисует в окне Scene луч, соответствующий траектории

3. Попробовать схитрить с выпуском пули.

Если вы хотите, чтобы пуля всегда летела ровно по центру, то можете выпускать её заведомо из центра экрана, но в z координате, равной координате `startBulletPosition.position.z`по направлению вдаль. Сам момент появления пули в точке, не совпадающей с дулом оружия, можно скрыть с помощью например анимации, основанной на `Particle System` (например анимация огня из дула.)

Также замечание по этому коду:

```
 clone = Instantiate(projectile, startBulletPosition.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
```

Частое создание однотипных объектов в момент надобности - довольно плохая и ресурсоемкая практика. Хорошей практикой в данной ситуации является использование техники [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling) (пул объектов). Если кратко, суть использования пула заключается в том, что вы *переиспользуете*

Comment: 1. Да, нужно, чтобы пулю было видно. Спасибо, сейчас попробую с Transform.Translate
2. Приложил скриншот - снаряд вылетает из орудия и летит в центр
3. Можно попробовать, но хотелось бы, чтобы стартовая точка была орудием, а ни центром экрана
Пули уничтожаются через три секунды после создания, но можно попробовать с пулом.

Comment: @dmitrykozyr если замаскировать анимацией появление пули, то будет не видно, так как срок жизни пули неочень большой. По поводу пула - то что пули живут 3 секунды ничуть не помешает реализации пула. В любом случае вы сможете прикинуть такой размер предзаготовленного пула, чтобы не пришлось в рантайме создавать новых объектов